# Python local module name shadowing standard lib in third package module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using [*libusb1*](https://github.com/vpelletier/python-libusb1) and noticed an import error when there is a *platform* module in my main module:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/duranda/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/usb1/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from . import libusb1
  File "/home/duranda/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/usb1/libusb1.py", line 199, in <module>
    libusb = _loadLibrary()
  File "/home/duranda/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/usb1/libusb1.py", line 161, in _loadLibrary
    system = platform.system()
AttributeError: module 'platform' has no attribute 'system'
```

This can be easily reproduced by launching a Python interpreter from a directory containing a `platform.py` or `platform/__init__.py` and then importing *usb1* using `import usb1`.

How is it possible that a local module shadows another module (in this case the `platform` module from the standard lib) **from a third party module**? To the best of my knowledge, *libusb1* [imports `platform` directly](https://github.com/vpelletier/python-libusb1/blob/master/usb1/libusb1.py#L47) and doesn't do anything crazy with globals.

Comment: How are you importing those modules?

Comment: _libusb1_ uses `import platform` and my module `import usb1`. There is no relative import with `.` notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the module **platform** in your working directory, and Python interpreter would insert current working directory into **sys.path** at the beginning. You could print ***sys.path*** out to check.

Thus, Python interpreter use the first one found when looking for module based on **sys.path**, which is your own module instead of the one in standard library.

A workaround (trick) is to move the current working directory to the end position; Note to put it at the top of file, and then import the module

```
import sys
# move the current working directory to the end position
sys.path = sys.path[1:] + sys.path[:1]
```

> More Comments:
>
> To reply @gelonida: suppose that we really want to use both modules,
>   we could import one first and give it an alias, and then modify
>   **sys.path** to import another one

```
import sys

# <------- newly added
_platform = patch_module('platform', '_platform')  # our own module

# move the current working directory to the end position
sys.path = sys.path[1:] + sys.path[:1]
```

And the above code use a **patch_module()** method

```
def patch_module(source_module_name, target_module_name):
    """ All imported modules are cached in *sys.modules*
    """
    __import__(source_module_name)

    m = sys.modules.pop(source_module_name)
    sys.modules[target_module_name] = m

    target_module = __import__(target_module_name)
    return target_module
```

Comment: Agreed, that should solve the problem. but as I mentioned. In my opinion it's best to rename your own module, such, that the module name conflict does not occur even if the path is not changed

Comment: However I forgot to mention, that requests will work then, but if the rest of your code tries to import your own platform.py it will fail as in this case the system's platform module has already been imported.

Answer (score 3):

add as first lines in your module:

```
import sys
print("\n".join(sys.path))

import platform
print("platform file is", platform.__file__)
```

This will probably show that the python path tries to first import your local modules and only then the system modules.

In other words, don't use local modules with names that conflict with system or third party module names.

#### More explanations:

If multiple modules import a module with the same name, then python imports the module only once.

Only the first import imports the module.
The second import will just point to the already imported module, which it will find in `sys.modules`

Thus a module name can be considered a unique pointer to python code.
(Try printing out `sys.modules`. This is a dict and will show you which modules are imported so far.)

So it doesn't matter whether an import statement is located in your file or in a third party file.

`import platform` will only point to one module. The one that is selected / found is the one that occurs first in the python path.

So self written modules should not have conflicting names with existing modules.

Comment: While I understand that using `import platform` in my module will import the local module, why does it use the local module for `platform` from imported third party modules/libraries as well?

Comment: look at the output of the python path.
This shows you where and in which order python will search for modules.
It doesn't matter, whether the import statement is in a third party module or in your own module. 
The search order for absolute imports is always the same.

Though you may change the order of the python path I think it is best  to rename your module.

Comment: enhanced my answer a little.